# Finding Grammatical Error In A Model SAT sentence

Tags: grammaticality

> Sacajawea, a Native American woman, whose ability to translate between indigenous languages and English was extremely helpful to the explorers, Louis and Clark, on their expedition to the Pacific Ocean.

In one of these videos http://www.veritasprep.com/free-sat-lessons/videos/on-demand.php#video this sentence is said to be grammatically incorrect, but where is the grammatical error? Can someone explain why the quoted sentence is incorrect ?

Comment: As a *sentence* it's not correct. It's just a long ***noun phrase*** (basically all adding further details about the "primary" noun ***Sacajawea***). You could "fix" it by including a verb (such as by replacing the first comma with ***was***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers post that as an answer.  :)

Comment: That sentence no verb.

Comment: @MattGutting - why isn't "was" the verb?

Comment: @FumbleFingers , As an isolated phrase, that is not a full MAJOR sentence, but within context, it could be a MINOR sentence. Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_%28linguistics%29#Major_and_minor_sentences

Comment: @Kristina: in this context, ***was*** is part of a [subordinate clause](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subordinateclause.htm), and refers back to the "subordinate noun subject" ***ability*** - *Main sentence as Matt **says** no verb*,

Comment: @KristinaLopez "was" is the subject in the subordinate clause beginning with "whose" and ending with "ocean". The subordinate clause can't stand alone (though you could make a question out of it); in the context of the full utterance, that clause is basically an appositive describing "Sacajawea".

Comment: @MattGutting Good to know - I learned something new today! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez To make it clearer, cut away some of the unnecessary clutter (it’s only there to distract the student taking the test anyway) and see if you don’t find that the ‘sentence’ rather stops before it gets anywhere: “Sacajawea, whose translations were helpful to Louis and Clark.” Might work as a caption to an image, but in most other circumstances, you’d be left thinking, “Yes? What about her?”.

Comment: Ok, @JanusBahsJacquet - now the lightbulb has been lit!  Joe McMahon's use of bolded words helped make it clearer also.  Very clever, these test makers!

Comment: Does the SAT question really spell Meriwether Lewis's last name _Louis_?

Comment: I'm not sure of that...i wrote it from memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to check this sentence is to remove the qualifiers and see what the core says:

> **Sacajawea,** *a Native American woman*, **whose ability** *to translate between indigenous languages and English* **was** *extremely* **helpful** *to the explorers, Louis and Clark, on their expedition to the Pacific Ocean*.

At this point it's now clear that there's no verb associated with "Sacajawea", which is the grammatical error.

> Sacajawea, whose ability was helpful.

Comment: It should be noted that this is **not** a grammatical error: no actual rules of grammar is violated. It simply means, as Prem points out in his comment, that we’re not dealing with a fully-fledged major sentence. If the sentence were used as the caption to a photo of Sacajawea in a book, it would be perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes - as a caption, there's an implied "This is" as a subject and verb.